# Django: Building a QuerySet Mixin for a model and a related model

Tags: django, django-models

My question is about creating a QuerySet Mixin which provides identical QuerySet methods for both a model and a related model. Here is example code, and the first class `ByPositionMixin` is what I am focused on:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.core.exceptions import FieldError

class ByPositionMixin(object):
    def batters(self):
        try:
            return self.exclude(positions=1)

        except FieldError:
            return self.exclude(position=1)

class PlayerQuerySet(QuerySet, ByPositionMixin):
    pass

class PlayerPositionQuerySet(QuerySet, ByPositionMixin):
    pass

class PlayerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return PlayerQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class PlayerPositionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return PlayerPositionQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class Position(models.Model):
    # pos_list in order ('P', 'C', '1B', '2B', '3B', 'SS', 'LF', 'CF', 'RF')
    # pos id / pk correspond to index value of pos_list(pos)
    pos = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, through='PlayerPosition')

    objects = PlayerManager()

class PlayerPosition(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    primary = models.BooleanField()

    objects = PlayerPositionManager()
```

Inside `ByPositionMixin`, I try `exclude(positions=1)` which queries against `PlayerQuerySet` and if that generates a `FieldError`, I try `exclude(position=1)` which queries against `PlayerPositionQuerySet`. The difference in field names is precise, a `Player()` has positions, but a `PlayerPosition()` has only one position. So the difference it the `exclude()` query is 'positions' / 'position'. Since I will have many custom queries (e.g. `batters()`, `pitchers()`, `by_position()` etc.), do I have to write out `try` / `except` code for each one?

Or is there a different approach which would let me write custom queries without having to try against one model and then against the other one?

UPDATE: basically, I have decided to write a kwarg helper function, which provides the correct kwargs for both `Player` and `PlayerPosition`. It's a little elaborate (and perhaps completely unnecessary), but should be able to be made to simplify the code for several custom queries.

```
class ByPositionMixin(object):
    def pkw(self, **kwargs):
        # returns appropriate kwargs, at the moment, only handles one kwarg
        key = kwargs.keys()[0]  # e.g. 'positions__in'
        value = kwargs[key]
        key_args = key.split('__')

        if self.model.__name__ == 'Player':
            first_arg = 'positions'

        elif self.model.__name__ == 'PlayerPosition':
            first_arg = 'position'

        else:
            first_arg = key_args[0]

        key = '__'.join([first_arg] + key_args[1:])
        return {key: value}

    def batters(self):  # shows how pkw() is used
        return self.exclude(**self.pkw(positions=1))
```

Comment: Is there a design reason you don't write specific methods on the specific ObjectManagers instead of complicated Mixins?

Comment: @professorDante By writing custom queries against QuerySet, they can be made to be chainable, which can be very valuable. For example, `Player.objects.batters().by_stat(HR__gte=20)`. Both `batters()` and `by_stat()` are custom queries. And the complete query is very legible. Another example, `PlayerPosition.objects.primary_position('SS').by_stat(HR__gte=20)`

Comment: Good point - but you just need to return another QS object to make them chainable. If you had a batters() method on your PlayerPositionManager, that answered a QS, you could chain and you know you are dealing with a PositionModel, eliminating the try blocks.

Comment: @professorDante I don't believe you can chain custom queries if they are written again models.Manager. So if `batters()` and `primary_position()` are both custom Manager methods, you cannot use `Player.objects.batters().primary_position('SS')`. Instead you have to write something like `Player.objects.batters().filter(positions='SS').filter(positions__primary=True)`.

Comment: Not sure that's right, look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager). You just need to write them on the Manager and the QuerySet. The Docs example is exactly what you need, no?

Comment: It's funny, but I have read that document several times, and use PassThroughManager for this code. My goals is to avoid writing the near-identical query twice, once for Player and once for PlayerPosition. The docs do explain the unchainability of methods against Managers I do believe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39386/discussion-between-cole-and-professordante)

Comment: Let me have a think - just seen your update. Quick idea for your new method - You can introspect each model to answer its own correct first_arg. Just have a method on the model to answer 'position', 'positions', etc. This removes all the if statements, and reduces to key = '__'.join([self.model.my_new_method()] + key_args[1:]), much more pithy.